# On $E[E[Y|X]|X]= E[Y|X]$

Tags: self-study, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am trying to simplify $E[YE[Y|X]|X]$ can I use this property:

$$E[E[Y|X]|X]= E[Y|X]$$

If yes I have never seen a Proof of this property (that seems very reasonable), could I have a reference? If I am right the correct result would be $$E[YE[Y|X]|X] = E[(Y|X)]^2$$

Comment: A [search on "iterated expectation"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=iterated%20expectation) gives you access to many discussions of such relationships.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the link, I have cleared my doubts on why $E[E[Y|X]|X]= E[Y|X]$ is true (basically $X \subseteq X$). But I am still unsure about $E[YE[Y|X]|X] = E[(Y|X)]^2$ where could I find this?

Comment: This is the *linearity* property of expectation.  A proof appears on the math site at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436459.

Comment: @whuber are you saying that the inner $E[Y|X]$ can be treated as a constant?  I was under the impression that $E[X|Y]$ was a random variable? Thanks

Comment: ${\rm E}[Y\mid X]$ is measurable with respect to sigma-algebra generated by $X$ and hence it can be 'treated as a constant' when conditioning on $X$. More generally, if $U$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then $E[UV\mid \mathcal{G}]=U{\rm E}[V\mid\mathcal{G}]$ for any pair of random variables $U,V$ such that the conditional expectations exist.

Comment: By establishing $E[E[Y|X]|X]= E[Y|X]$ you have verified that $E[Y|X]$ acts like a constant with respect to conditional expectations.  It sounds, though, like you have a separate question that needs answering (and @Stefan has supplied a rigorous answer to it), so I will vote to re-open this post.